# SQL Trigger not updating field

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

When i select a value in one table, the same value must populate the other table.
For example:
Please see image attached:
[image]

The problem i am having is when i update the first field stage (left hand side), to say Stage2, the uStage field stays the same.. It should update to Stage2 as well..

The Ustage table has the same stage values as the Stage table so I know it needs to select the corresponding Value however i have tried all sorts to get this to work but it doesnt want to update:

Here is my Trigger code:

```
USE [SKY]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[SetIT]    Script Date: 2018/10/04 19:52:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SetIT] ON [dbo].[AMGR_Opportunity_Tbl]
AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @RecordId int
DECLARE @Stage varchar(750)
Declare @ID int
begin
--check to see if we have any records in the inserted set
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM inserted ) BEGIN

--set up the cursor that we use to iterate over the recordset
DECLARE I CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT Record_Id FROM Inserted;
OPEN I
FETCH NEXT FROM I INTO @RecordId;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN


SELECT @Stage = STAGE FROM STAGE WHERE ID = @ID;


--insert the UDF value
INSERT INTO O_Ustage(Client_id,Contact_Number,O_Ustage)
SELECT Opp_Id, 0, @Stage
FROM inserted WHERE Record_Id = @RecordId AND Opp_Type = 0;


--update the current stage

    UPDATE stage set stage=@stage WHERE  
    ID=@ID;


FETCH NEXT FROM I INTO @RecordId;
END
CLOSE I
DEALLOCATE I
END
END
GO
```

Please assist in helping me figure out how to update the USTAGE field.

Below is the data that is in the Stage table

[image]

If i change the field 'Stage' below, then 'Ustage' also needs to change.. At the moment it is not doing it:

[image]

The opportunity table has 50 columns and stage table 2 columns.
When I change the stage on the opportunity table to Stage2 then the Ustage value must also change to Stage2.. Both values need to correspond

Comment: You declare @ID but never set it to anything so it will always be NULL. Therefore the entire body of your trigger does nothing. I would suggest using a set based update here to handle multiple rows instead of a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger code has a lot of problems, but here's one that will definitely cause it not to work:

```
SELECT @Stage = STAGE FROM STAGE WHERE ID = @ID;
```

Prior to that line of code, you never populate `@ID`, so it's value will be `NULL`.   Therefore you will get `NULL` for `@Stage`, which is what you later insert into the `O_UStage` column.

Maybe you meant to use `@RecordId` on that line instead of `@ID`?

Comment: Thanks All.. if I put the ID = 1 the stage value in ustage updates to stage1.. However the values for stage in ustage are as follows: stage1 has ID = 1, stage2 has ID = 2, stage3 has ID = 3.. so if the opportunity stage is equal to stage 2 then the trigger must look for the corresponding value in ustage and update the existing value with the new value..

Comment: Sorry, the comment above isn't clear at all.   Can you edit your question and show visual examples of what you mean?

Comment: question updated with the values in the stage table as per my comment above

Comment: That's not enough.  What do you mean by "if I put the ID = 1"?   What do you mean by " if the opportunity stage is equal to stage 2 then the trigger must look for the corresponding value in ustage and update the existing value with the new value"?   Show examples in your question because these sentences don't make any sense to me.

Comment: i am trying to explain as best i can